# AutoMapper SourceMemberNameTransformer

Tags: automapper

I wanted to register a custom naming convention for a property that I have on a number of domain objects and associated view models.

The domain object has an enum property `PublishStatus` and the view model has a boolean property `Published`.

If I create a custom `SourceMemberNameTransformer` like on [How do I get AutoMapper to deal with a custom naming convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866369/how-do-i-get-automapper-to-deal-with-a-custom-naming-convention), do I just return the original string for properties that don't match `PublishStatus`?

Comment: Warning: it seems the property "SourceMemberNameTransformer" has been removed in after version 2.1.1 of Automapper

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly you probably want a `ValueResolver`. Something like:

```
public class PublishStatusResolver : ValueResolver<PublishStatus, bool>
{
    protected override bool ResolveCore(PublishStatus status)
    {
        return status == PublishStatus.Published;
    }
}
```

Then in mapping code you call it like:

```
.ForMember(dto => dto.Published, 
           opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PublishStatusResolver>()
                     .FromMember(src => src.PublishStatus))
```

Comment: no I'm trying to avoid mapping like this. I'm trying to register a naming convention so that AutoMapper automatically uses my ValueResolver without be explicitly declaring it on each property.