# How to implement custom naming resolver for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

How to map following class using AutoMapper **without explicitly indicating all member mappings**:

```
public class Source
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ... (huge amount of other properties)
}
```

to class:

```
public class Destination
{
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    ... (huge amount of other properties)
}
```

using translation class:

```
var translations = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "FirstName", "Imie" },
    { "LastName", "Nazwisko" },
    ... (huge amount of other translations)
}
```

Comment: you have to specify explicilty because names are totally different in both types

Comment: You might want to take a look at: [Usage of AutoMapper when property names are different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186160/usage-of-automapper-when-property-names-are-different?rq=1). Specifically, you should create your own [INamingConvention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866369/how-do-i-get-automapper-to-deal-with-a-custom-naming-convention)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it.

Consider the following method:

```
public void CreateMapBasedOnDictionary<TSource, TDestination>(IDictionary<string, string> mapping_dictionary)
{
    var mapping_expression = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();

    foreach (var kvp in mapping_dictionary)
    {
        string source_property_name = kvp.Key;
        string destination_property_name = kvp.Value;

        Type member_type = typeof (TSource).GetProperty(source_property_name).PropertyType;

        mapping_expression = mapping_expression.ForMember(destination_property_name, x =>
        {
            typeof (IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource>)
                .GetMethod("MapFrom", new []{typeof(string)})
                .MakeGenericMethod(member_type)
                .Invoke(x, new[] { source_property_name });
        });
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var translations = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"FirstName", "Imie"},
    {"LastName", "Nazwisko"},

};

CreateMapBasedOnDictionary<Source, Destination>(translations);

Source src = new Source()
{
    FirstName = "My first name",
    LastName = "My last name"
};

var dst = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Destination>(src);
```

Here is the explanation for the `CreateMapBasedOnDictionary` method:

AutoMapper already has an overload of `ForMember` that allows you to specify the destination property by name. We are good here.

It also has an overload of `MapFrom` that allows you to specify the source property by name. The problem with this overload however, is that it requires a generic parameter (`TMember`) for the property type.

We can solve this issue, by using reflection to get the type of the property and then dynamically invoke the `MapFrom` method with the appropriate `TMember` type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx):

```
private TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, Dictionary<string, string> mapData)
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class, new()
{
    if (source == null) return null;
    if (mapData == null) mapData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    TDestination destination = new TDestination();
    PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in sourceProperties)
    {
        string destPropertyName = mapData.ContainsKey(property.Name) ? mapData[property.Name] : property.Name;
        PropertyInfo destProperty = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(destPropertyName);
        if (destProperty == null) continue;
        destProperty.SetValue(destination, property.GetValue(source));
    }
    return destination;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
Destination mapped = Map<Source, Destination>(source, translations);
```

Comment: Thank you for post. But your solution does not use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yacoub-massad answer, I have made this solution:

```
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

var sourceProperties = typeof(Source).GetProperties();
foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
{
    var sourcePropertyName = sourceProperty.Name;
    var destinationPropertyName = translations[sourceProperty.Name];

    map.ForMember(destinationPropertyName, mo => mo.MapFrom<string>(sourcePropertyName));
}

var src = new Source() { FirstName = "Maciej", LastName = "Lis" };
var dest = Mapper.DynamicMap<Destination>(src);
```

Comment: The reason I didn't simply use `string`, is that I assumed that your classes might have properties of other types (e.g. `int`)

Comment: For example, in the same class you could have some properties of type `string` and some other properties of type `int`